# asynchronous function producing inconsistent results

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, future, stdasync

I have a function that runs asynchronously. Unfortunately, it only spits out the correct answer on occasion. The values represented by `futures[i].get()` change each time I run the code. I'm new to multithreading.

```
double async_func() const {

    vector<future<double>> futures;

    double val = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        futures.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, [&] {return minor(i,0).determinant();}) );
    }       
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) 
        val += futures[i].get();

    return val;
}
```

Comment: Don't you have to wait() ? futures[i].wait(), before .get() ?

Comment: I was under the impression that .get() handles this automatically.

Comment: Right. Correct answer provided by someone else. Well, I learned something today.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem lies in the capture by reference.

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
   futures.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, [&] // capture by reference!
   {
       return minor(i,0).determinant();
   }));
}
```

This is a problem, because each executed method doesn't get its own value of `i`, but a reference to the loop variable `i`. Hence, as soon as `i` is evaluated for the function call `minor(i, 0)`, it may have already changed. Even worse, the function call may not have been executed yet before the end of the loop. Hence `i` may have been destroyed before it's been used.

---

If the above description isn't enough, maybe this timeline can help. Note that this is not a real situation, it's just an illustration.

Assume that iterating `i` takes 2 time steps, evaluating the parameters of the function takes 2 steps and starting a thread takes 5 steps (on a real machine probably way more!). The job done by each thread may take several thousand steps (that's why we parallelize them, right?).

```
Time -->
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 ...
^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^  ^  ^  ^  ^
| | | | | | | | | | |  |  |  |  Thread 3 function call.
| | | | | | | | | | |  |  |  Thread 3 evaluate parameters (i == garbage!).
| | | | | | | | | | |  |  Thread 3 start; Thread 2 function call.
| | | | | | | | | | |  Thread 2 evaluate parameters (i == garbage!).
| | | | | | | | | | Destroy i; Thread 2 start; Thread 1 function call.
| | | | | | | | | Loop condition broken; Thread 1 evaluate parameters (i == 4 !).
| | | | | | | | Thread 0 function call; Thread 1 start; i = 4;
| | | | | | | Thread 3 request to start; Thread 0 evaluate parameters (i == 3 !).
| | | | | | Thread 0 start; i = 3;
| | | | | Thread 2 request to start.
| | | | i = 2.
| | | Thread 1 request to start.
| | i = 1.
| Thread 0 request to start.
Create i, i = 0.
```

So some threads get meaningful data, others won't. Depending on actual timings, it might be possible to increment `i` at the same time as evaluating its value for the function parameter in which case you have a race condition.

---

The resolution is by capturing `i` by value:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
   futures.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, [=] // capture by value
   {
       return minor(i,0).determinant();
   }));
}
```

Recommendation: when dealing with asynchronous bits, be explicit about what your capture:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
   futures.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, [i] // explicit capture by value
   {
       return minor(i,0).determinant();
   }));
}
```

You also should avoid having reallocations to your vector of futures. Simply add `futures.reserve(rows)` before the loop.

Comment: THANK YOU. I don't know why I didn't just post on here earlier.

Comment: @Gustav: The best way to thank [stefan](http://stackoverflow.com/users/985296/stefan) is to **accept** his answer :)

Comment: @Gustav you're very welcome. I did suffer from that bug before, so I'm glad to have helped someone by sharing this insight. (actually I did only visit this question, because my nick name in the real world is Gustav ;-) )

Comment: @ereOn: I was getting to that :) Was just so excited that my code wasn't completely incorrect, that instead it was off by one character.

Comment: @stefan: I chose it because I'm a big fan of a hockey player by the same name.